# Showing K2 itemID in frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

Well as title says, I need to show ITEMID of K2 Item in frontend of that specific item...

I know how to do this for Joomla Article, but is for K2 different?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.
Thanks :)

```
<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>
```

In k2 templates in item.php just put that code and item ID will be visible.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to show it, the best practice is to override K2 templates in your template folder, just to not lose your template modifications every K2 update.